# Why isn't Mojo Jojo using live bait?

Tags: powerpuff-girls

In *Powerpuff Girls* (original series) season 6 episode 07a “Crazy mixed up Puffs”, Mojo Jojo uses a doll with a magnetophone as bait.  The doll is a likeness of the little girl that has annoyed Mojo earlier in the episode.

**Why is Mojo Jojo using a doll instead of capturing the girl and using her as live bait?**

[image: (illustration showing the mechanical doll)]